# Where in memory are variables stored in C++?

Tags: c++

If I have code like this:

```
int e;
int* f;

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    int* d;
}
```

Where in memory are these variables stored?
And, what's the problem with defining global variables (out of a function, like main in this case)?

Comment: Read this : http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/009.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a,b,c and d will exist on the stack.  If you were to create an instance of an int (with malloc or new), that would go on the heap - but the pointer called 'd' would still exist on the stack.

e and f are allocated space in the memory space of the app, in the so-called 'Data segment' - see:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

You also asked about stack size: that's configured by the compiler, see here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Oh thanks. Very useful the info about the data segment! And about the stack size thank you, I have the things more clear now :)

Comment: With any optimizing compiler, locals being on the stack is an iffy sort of thing.  It may be useful conceptually to say they are all on the stack, but most of the time this won't reflect reality.

Comment: Agreed, in order to do much with them they will be transferred to registers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register).  But asked 'where are local variables allocated' the answer is 'the stack' :)

Comment: Hang on. This answer talks as if C++ defines such variables to "exist on the stack". It does not. C++ specifies an abstract machine. To discuss stacks and memory we must identify a physical implementation. You're basically spreading misinformation :(

Answer (score 9):

There are actually no guarantees about placement of variables in memory, only behavior.

But on most (perhaps all) practical systems, `e` and `f` will be in the global data section, while `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are in a mix of registers and on the call stack.  Both `f` and `d` can point to anywhere in memory (well, with an MMU this isn't precisely true, they can point anywhere in the subset of memory which is mapped into the process).

Comment: Thanks. Then I can define as many global variables as I want without having performance issues / space?

Comment: @Puy: You will certainly have design issues with many global variables.

Comment: You can have a great many global variables, but all statically allocated variables have to be initialized which will slow down program startup.  It probably won't be enough to notice.  As Fred says, though, using lots of global variables will make your program hard to maintain, so it isn't recommended.  Better would be file-scoped variables without extern linkage, this can be done using the nameless namespace in C++ or the `static` keyword in C (not recommended for C++), and will not lead to spaghetti code as easily as global variables.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think this matters? Note that in modern C++, having local pointer variables is extremely rare.

On a typical system, a, b, c and d will live on the stack. But that's an implementation detail, the language standard says nothing specific about that.

Comment: Is there any way, I can know what's the size of the stack in a standard PC?

Comment: ... and finding out what the stack size for a given thread is OS-specific. In Windows, you can get this information by retrieving Thread Information Blocks (32-bit) or Thread Environment Blocks (64-bit).

Comment: @Puyover What is "a standard PC"?

Answer (score 3):

In general, a,b,c,d* will be defined on the program stack, though the C++ ISO standard doesn't specify where variables should be defined.

For your second question, the problem with global variables is that they have no protection. For a simple script/application relying on globals might be okay, but in libraries, and more complex code it produces a potential problem: any code can change the values of variables with global scope at anytime, leaving any code that relies on global variables in an undesired state.

Further, since variables are in the global scope, they're open to potential naming collisions if you make use of any other code that defines global variables with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The main point is the scope of the variables, which defines their lifetime. The variables outsie of main will be available for the duration of your program. The variables inside main will be availalbe for the duration of the main() function.

In practice, the function-scoped variables are usually allocated on the stack, while global variables are allocated on the heap, but this is an implementation detail.

The main problem with global variables is controlling access, and they can be difficult to work with in a multi-threaded program.

EDIT: As @FredOverflow points out below, the globals are typically allocated in the data area that is set up when the executable image is loaded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure global variables aren't allocated from the heap but from the data segment or something.

Comment: @Fred - you're right. My thinking didn't keep up with my typing!